# How to get Patients using medicalNumber not Id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

"I'm coding serves (REST API), and want to create action that get specific patient by it's medicalNumber like getting patient by id. How can i do this ?

" i tried to do ...

```
//GET: Api/GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber/657847
        public Patients GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber(int medicalNumber)
        {
            var patients = db.Patients.SingleOrDefault(e => e.medicalNumber == medicalNumber);

            if (patients == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return patients;

        }
```

Like...

```
 //GET: Api/GetPatients/1
        public Patients GetPatients(int id)
        {
            var patients = db.Patients.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

            if (patients == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return patients;

        }
```

get patient by id work i think this is work because Id is the key of my table

```
public class Patients
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public int medicalNumber { get; set; }


        public string userName { get; set; }


        public int phoneNumber { get; set; }


        public string address { get; set; }


        public string email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tests> Tests { get; set; }
    }
```

but getting patients using there medical numbers not work get all patient..

Comment: It should work. What do you see when you step through `GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber` in the debugger?

Comment: get all patients

Comment: debugger does'nt work !

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/s9li2N6.png)

Comment: My guess is you're hitting `GetPatients()` instead. Have you got your routing set up correctly?

Comment: So the code in your question isn't your actual code as shown in the screenshot? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this?

```
public Patients GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber(int medicalNumber)
        {
            Patients patient = db.Patients.Where(e => e.medicalNumber == medicalNumber).FirstOrDefault();

            if (patients == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            return patient;

        }
```

Can you specify the problem? are getting patients with your cousult before the return? or your metod doesent return a Patient object ?

Comment: my problem this method doesn't get the specific  patient, get all patients

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: what is your suggestion ??

Comment: I think your url is wrong, you are landing in the metod in line 22.  You have to specify the new variable api works with the id value, in your case, you change to the number instead so try: Api/GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber?medicalNumber=657847

Comment: https://localhost:44368/Api/GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber?medicalNumber=657847

Comment: in your web api config you have this metod `
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );` as you see it works with the id not with patientnumber so, you specify it in the url like Api/GetPatientsbyMedicalNumber?medicalNumber=657847 or add a new route to work with that variable instead of id